# Magento : Call to a core block inside my module

Tags: php, magento

Hi,
I am writing a Magento module. For that I want to call a core block inside my module's handler. I don't want to modify or extend the core block. I just want to call it inside my layout handler. Any suggestions?

The block I want to insert is located in

```
adminhtml/sales/order/view/history.php
```

Following handler is in the sales.xml which contains the above Histrory.php block

```
 <adminhtml_sales_order_addcomment>
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_addcomment>
```

This is my layout.xml

```
       <orderadmin_adminhtml_orderadmin_search> 
        <update handle="orderadmin_orderadmin_search" />
         <reference name="content"> 
     <!-- I want to insert the following block --> 
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml" output="toHtml"/> 
</reference> 
</orderadmin_adminhtml_orderadmin_search>
```

But it causes the following error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\View\History.php on line 79

Comment: What do you mean by call? You can just insert it via `<block type="core/template"... />`

Comment: yes. I want to insert the core block inside my handler in layout.xml

Comment: Yes, just do it. And if you have done it, show the code if it doesn't work

Comment: <orderadmin_adminhtml_orderadmin_search>
  <update handle="orderadmin_orderadmin_search" />
  <reference name="content">
   <block type="orderadmin/adminhtml_search" name="search_order" />
   <!-- I want to insert the following block -->
   <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
  </reference>
 </orderadmin_adminhtml_orderadmin_search>

Comment: can you please edit your question? code in comments is unreadable

Comment: Edited the question. Please any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is, did you check, what this line is? `$this->getOrder()->getId()` There is no order in your block. you need to call in your controller `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('order_history')->setOrder($anyOrder);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do the with xml layout, that is infact correct and will work as it is.

the issue is because this block is expecting an order to be in the registry, to enable it to grab the history.

You should set an order (the order you wish to use for viewing history) in the registry inside either your controller, or your modules block before the history block is rendered.

```
// load your order here..
Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Error was fixed after saving the order id in register.

Comment: Hi ,I added the block inside my handler. But when I add a comment and submit it is not showing in comments list. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like this in your code :

```
<!-- this is my handler -->
<orderadmin_adminhtml_orderadmin_search>
        <update handle="orderadmin_orderadmin_search" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="orderadmin/adminhtml_search" name="search_order" />
            <!-- I want to call the core block here -->
```

> Pick up from core layouts the block you wanted and paste here as it
>   is, it will get rendered

```
        </reference>
    </orderadmin_adminhtml_orderadmin_search>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I've already tried that. But it didn't work. Please any suggesstion?

Comment: Hi, I want to insert the following block in adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml" output="toHtml"/>

Comment: In your controller's action have you written $this->loadLayout()->renderLaout();...?

Comment: some times direct `reference"content"` does not execute all the childern althought it should. u can try encapsulating them in a wrapper. It is not a recommended solution but u can try it.

`<reference name="content"><block type="orderadmin/adminhtml_search" name="search_order"><block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_history" name="order_history" template="sales/order/view/history.phtml"/></block>` and ur phtml try with `echo $this->getChildHtml('order_history')`